# Can't insert sha1 hash as primary key into sqlite using sqlachemy

Tags: database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Just as the title says. I am using python `FastAPI` for context. And also if just hardcode a hash like: "1", it works so I know the problem is in that part of the code.

```
class Object(Base):
   __tablename__ = "objects"
   oid = Column(String, primary_key=True)
   name = Column(String)
   blob = Column(BLOB)

@app.post("/upload")
def upload(files: List[UploadFile] = File(..., description= "Upload your files"), db: Session = Depends(database.get_db)):
   try:
      for file in files:
         contents = file.file.read()
         obj_oid = hashlib.sha1(contents).hexdigest()
         new_object = models.Object(name=file.filename, blob=contents, oid= str(obj_oid) )
         db.add(new_object)
      db.commit()

   except Exception as e:
      db.rollback
      return {"message": f"There was an error uploading the file(s): {e}"}
   finally:
      db.close()

   return {"message": f"Successfuly uploaded {[file.filename for file in files]}"}
```

When I do the old data type as Integer I get the error that the int is too big. When I do it as a String as shown here, I get: datatype mismatch What should I do here?

Exact error message: sqlite3.IntegrityError) datatype mismatch\n[SQL: INSERT INTO objects (oid, name, blob) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]\n[parameters: ('647968efebd7339771cb51fb960c501074deceb9', 'code.txt', <memory at 0x0000015D9FD9F280>)]\n(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/gkpj)"

This question feels trivial but I have not been able to solve it or find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have changed the type of the `oid` column in your model class from `Integer` to `String` but this will not change the type of the column in the database table.

The simplest solution is to drop the table and recreate it with `db.create_all()`, or delete the database file and let `db.create_all()` recreate all your tables.

If dropping the table not acceptable then you will need to use a solution like flask-migrate to make the change, or manually drop and recreate the column in the SQLite shell.

Note that all of these approaches entail data loss except for migrating using flask-migrate.